# How to show jquery datetimepicker in fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show jquery datepicker in fullscreen?

I create a datepicker at a input tag,and it's working well.
But when I fullscreen ,the control panel is behind the fullscreen div.
Can I move datepicker to the fullscreen div or let it show up to fullscreen div?

here is my code:

```
    <body>
        <div class="ddfullscreen">
            <input class="datepicker">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        //fullscreen
        var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("ddfullscreen");
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(elem){
                if (this.requestFullscreen) {
                this.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                this.msRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                this.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                this.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                }   
            });
            }
    </script>
    <script>
        //datetimepicker
        $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
            format: "Y-m-d",
            timepicker:false
        });    
    </script>
```

datepicker:

examples:https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

github:https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

Comment: First inspect what the dynamic css class is adding in datePicker and then use that class to override the css using $(window).height() and $(window).width().

Answer (score 0):

I check the option at [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) , and i find onGenerate() function ,so I fix code like this

```
    <script>
        //datetimepicker
        $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
            format: "Y-m-d",
            timepicker:false,
            onGenerate:function(){
                $(".ddfullscreen")[0].append(this[0])
            }
        });    
    </script>
```